# convergence sequence and continuous functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, continuity

I have the following question: assume $C$ is a subset (we can assume it is convex and compact) of a Banach space $(X,\|\cdot\|)$, $f:C\longrightarrow C$ continuous and $x_{0}\in C$ a fixed point of $f$. Also, let $(x_{n})_{n\geq 1}\subset C$ be a sequence having a subsequence converging to $x_{0}$, and such that

$$\Big| \|x_{n+1}-x_{0}\|-\|f(x_{n})-f(x_{0})\| \Big|\leq c_{n},$$

for each $n\geq 1$, where $c_{n}$ is a positive sequence of numbers with $c_{n}\rightarrow 0$.

From the above conditions, can we derive that $x_{n}\rightarrow x_{0}$?

I know that if $f$ is nonexpansive (i.e. $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq \|x-y\|$) the assett is true under some additional conditions on the sequence $(c_{n})_{n\geq 1}$,but assuming only the continuity of $f$, it is not clear.

What do you think?

Many thanks in advance for your comments!

Answer (score 3):

Without additional conditions on the sequence $(c_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ (maybe, that the series $\sum c_n$ converges) the asset may be false even for the segment  $[0,1]$ endowed with the standard metric and the identity map $f$. As a counterexample it suffices to put $x_0=0$ and $\{x_n\}$ any sequence of points of $[0,1]$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |x_{n}-x_{n+1}|=0$,  $\{x_n\}$ contains a subsequence convergent to $x_0$, but  $\{x_n\}$ does not converges to $0$.

Comment: Thanks Alex!! Yes, we can assume that the series defined by the sequence c_{n} is convergent. Some idea?

Comment: @user123043 I guess there still may be a counterexample with $[0,1]$ and $x_0=0$, but we have to adjust the sequence $\{x_n\}$  and the function $f$, which looks technically hard. So later I can try to pose this task as a course paper topic for one of our students. :-)

Comment: Many thanks Alex Ravsky!! I think (bythe "experiments" done with the PC) that the result may be true if the sequence c_{n} is convergent, but I do not find a formal proof :(